# How to store and fetch large-ish private files using GitHub Actions?

Tags: github, github-actions, git-lfs

I have some files that my tests depend on. They are not huge, but not small. Say, 5-10M in total (compressed).

I want to download them and use them in GitHub Actions to run tests.

What is a good option for storing and downloading these files?

I've thought of:

1. Just check them in. However, I don't want to make my GitHub repo big because of these. They will change over time, and checking in a new version each time would leave a bunch of stuff in the repo, but I'm not super interested in versioning them.
2. Check them into [git large file storage](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-git-large-file-storage). This might be better, in that the main repo only has a pointer in it, but it's not obvious to me exactly how to use this. There are [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files), though.
3. Use a Google action to download them from Google Drive.  ([satackey](https://github.com/satackey/action-google-drive) uses [skicka](https://github.com/google/skicka), which has been put in read-only mode, but maybe [google-drive-download-action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/google-drive-download-action)?)

Comment: LFS seems reasonable. Exactly what LFS is designed for and seems to solve the objections you have mentioned in (1). Using remote object storage (S3, or I suppose Google Drive) also seems fine, but it may make it difficult for people to test locally, whereas git users can pull LFS files -- by contrast, contributors may not have permission to pull files from your Google Drive or other remote storage. But maybe that's actually what you want since you mention these are "private" files. If this is a public repo and viewers shouldn't have access then Google Drive (or remote storage) would be the way

Comment: Only 1. will ensure that your project has a self contained build incl. the files to test them. If you don't know yet if that's what you want for all the future, keep the 5-10 M test fixtures in a subtree of their own. Then have a development branch / worktree to operate on, build locally and push to Github combined (or checkout from a different branch into the test-tree while setting up the remote build). Both 2. and 3. require extra configuration management and 2. (LFS) contradicts your reuqirement to not version control those files. Different branch  and subtree allows you to rewrite history

Comment: i think the most effective solution depends on a few things: file type (txt or binary), how many files (2 or 3 big ones  vs many small), and how often they change compared to number of times theyre used. could you provide some more info on that?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using git large file storage.  As commenters mentioned, then anyone with permissions to the repository can get the files.  It's the proper integration.

We have a private repo, so it is a smooth way to handle permissions.

Thanks all!